# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined - YQL

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-framework-7

I try to get weather data from Yahoo YQL. The request worked, but it stop to work...

```
var yql = encodeURIComponent('select * from weather.forecast where woeid = "' + woeid + '"and u="c"');
        $$.ajax({
             //dataType: "json",
            // contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
              dataType: 'text',
              url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + yql + '&format=json',
              timeout: 5000,

              //Sucesso
              success: function(data){
                var resultados = data.query.results.channel;

                var graus = resultados.item.condition.temp;
                var cod_condicao = resultados.item.condition.code;
                var nascer = resultados.astronomy.sunrise;
                var poente = resultados.astronomy.sunset;
                var umidade = resultados.atmosphere.humidity + '%';
                var vento = resultados.wind.speed + 'KM/H'
                var forecast = resultados.item.forecast;
}
```

The result is:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined

What is wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Try debugging it by looking at what `console.log(data);` outputs in the success function.

Comment: console.log(data) returns the request perfectly... :(

Comment: `'select * from weather.forecast where woeid = "' + woeid + '"and u="c"'` shouldn't there be a space between the apostrophe and the "and" keyword?

Comment: Why is `dataType` set to `"text"`? What is the full URL?

Comment: It was an attempt to make it work ...

Comment: https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%20%3D%20%22455827%22and%20u%3D%22c%22&format=json

Comment: The URL is malformed. What is `woeid`?

Comment: The url appears malformed in this comment field... Woeid is the place id to search...

Comment: The link - https://anotepad.com/notes/8i9qkk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `dataType:'json'`.

```js
var woeid = 455827; // example id
var yql = encodeURIComponent('select * from weather.forecast where woeid = "' + woeid + '"and u="c"');
$.ajax({
  dataType: 'json',
  url: 'https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=' + yql + '&format=json',
  timeout: 5000,
  //Sucesso
  success: function(data) {
    console.log(data);
    var resultados = data.query.results.channel;

    var graus = resultados.item.condition.temp;
    var cod_condicao = resultados.item.condition.code;
    var nascer = resultados.astronomy.sunrise;
    var poente = resultados.astronomy.sunset;
    var umidade = resultados.atmosphere.humidity + '%';
    var vento = resultados.wind.speed + 'KM/H'
    var forecast = resultados.item.forecast;
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: This fix the "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'results' of undefined" and return 200 OK and the data, but fires the "error" block of my ajax...

Comment: @PedroAntônio Run the code I posted. It works as expected, and I am using the exact same code you have. Therefore the problem is somewhere else in your code that you didn't post.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.getJSON()` with URL

```
"https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select * from weather.forecast where woeid='45‌​5827' and u='c'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback="
```

```
"https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D'45%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B5827'%20and%20u%3D'c'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback="
```

```js
$.getJSON("https://query.yahooapis.com/v1/public/yql?q=select%20*%20from%20weather.forecast%20where%20woeid%3D'45%E2%80%8C%E2%80%8B5827'%20and%20u%3D'c'&format=json&diagnostics=true&callback=")
  .then(function(data) {
    var resultados = data.query.results.channel;
    var graus = resultados.item.condition.temp;
    var cod_condicao = resultados.item.condition.code;
    var nascer = resultados.astronomy.sunrise;
    var poente = resultados.astronomy.sunset;
    var umidade = resultados.atmosphere.humidity + '%';
    var vento = resultados.wind.speed + 'KM/H'
    var forecast = resultados.item.forecast;
    console.log(resultados, graus, cod_condicao
                , nascer, poente, umidade, vento, forecast);
  })
  .fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
     console.log(errorThrown)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```